# Getting the value of a multimap in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, multimap

I was wondering how do I retrieve the value of a multi map in C++

Comment: Awfully vague there.  Want to fill in some details?  In general, a Multimaps store key-value pairs.   Do you want all the values?  One particular value?  What have you tried, and where did it fail?

Comment: I know in perl I can access the value by giving the map a key?? How would I do something similiar in C++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multimap has internal structure represented as `std::pair<T_k, T_v>`. It has first, second members. `first` is the key and `second` is the value associated with the key.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){

        multimap<int,int> a;
        a.insert(pair<int,int> (1,2));
        a.insert(pair<int,int> (1,2));
        a.insert(pair<int,int> (1,4));
        for (multimap<int,int>::iterator it= a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
                cout << it->first << "\t" << it->second << endl ;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Output :

> 1 2
>   1 2
>   1 4

Answer (score 8):

To retrieve the value of a `multimap` you need to use its name.

So if you have a multimap called `myMap`, you can retrieve its value with the expression:

```
myMap
```

Once you have its value, you can copy it into another multimap, or you can call member functions on it to decompose its value into smaller logical subvalues.

---

To access a particular range of mapped values that correspond to a a given key (called `myKey` in this example), you can use:

```
myMap.equal_range(myKey)
```

This evaluates to a `std::pair` of `iterator`s (or `const_iterators` if `myMap` is `const`), which delimit the range of key-value pairs with keys that are equivalent to `myKey`.

For example (assume that myMap is a map from T1 to T2, where T1 and T2 are not dependent types):

```
typedef std::multimap<T1, T2>::iterator iter;
for (std::pair<iter, iter> range(myMap.equal_range(myKey));
     range.first != range.second;
     ++range.first)
{
    //In each iteration range.first will refer to a different object
    //In each case, range.first->first will be equivalent to myKey
    //and range.first->second will be a value that range.first->first maps to.
}
```

Comment: Your description is little wrong.         In each case, range.first->first will be equivalent to myKey
and range.first->second will be a value that range.first.first maps to.

Comment: Worth noting that the returned `std::pair`'s `first` and `second` (iterator) can be also obtained by `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, respectively. See [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range).